# Changing Schema.xml in SolrCloud setup

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

how do i change the schema.xml for a collection in SolrCloud?

I have set up a zookeeper-ensemble on 3 nodes and i guess i could make the changes there, but don't know exactly.

Comment: as far as i know, after changing your schema, reloading the related core on leader node should update the schema for all... not quite sure if you need to reload the core on other nodes too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Solr 5.x released, a Schema API was implemented to change the Schema more easily:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API

Answer (score 4):

You can reload schema.xml for cores on SolrCloud by using zkCli.sh

More details in the Stackoverflow link: [Reloading Zoo keeper solr conf (schema.xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830090/reloading-zoo-keeper-solr-conf-schema-xml)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use 1 node as a bootstrapper, you may add a bootstrap_configdir pointing to your configuration directory. Restarting the service would upload configuration files.
Another option is to use the ZkCli  - you can find the usage examples here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud