# solr collection - how to modify schema.xml using vi

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I created a Solr collection from some existing schema and configuration using:

```
-d server/solr/classiccore1/conf
```

While I can see schema.xml and solrconfig.xml in the *Solr Admin UI* for a solr collection I just created, I can't find it on the filesystem.

My SolrCloud contains 2 nodes and 1 embedded zookeeper instance.

Is there any way to modify schema.xml on filesystem rather then using relevant APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Solr in the cloud configuration, all the configuration files has to be available in the cluster - that means that the files are stored in Zookeeper, which keeps all the state and configuration for your cluster.

See [Reloading Zookeeper solr conf (schema.xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15834703/137650), as well as the [examples in the reference manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+ZooKeeper+to+Manage+Configuration+Files) on how you upload a new configuration file or configuration set to Zookeeper.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what you are describing and links you provided needs a standalone zookeeper installation. while I mentioned I don't have separate zookeeper installation . I am using embedded zookeeper.

Comment: That should be the same - the embedded zookeeper is still exposed through a regular host. It's just bundled (and started) with Solr. The Zookeepers still need to communicate with each other. `When Solr runs an embedded zookeeper server, it defaults to using the solr port plus 1000 for the zookeeper client port. In addition, it defaults to adding one to the client port for the zookeeper server port, and two for the zookeeper leader election port. So with Solr running at 8983, the embedded zookeeper server used port 9983 for the client port and 9984,9985 for the server ports.`

Comment: Agree. I was missing bigger difference between operating solo core vs collection backed by zookeeper.