# ZooKeeper & Solr Cloud - I need change Schema.xml file

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I would like to update the `/configs/DMF-index-transformed/schema.xml` file in ZooKeeper with `/home/~/Desktop/schema.xml`. I have a link similar to this problem [same problem and resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15834703/3673767). But there was a desire to open a new topic because it was my problem.

```
sh zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -zkhost 127.0.0.1:9983 -collection DMF-index-transformed -confname ??? -solrhome ??? -confdir ???
```

I just want to update (editing in vi or editor) the schema.xml file. How can I organize the above command according to this problem?

solr -version 4.9.0

zooKeeper -version 3.4.6

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the collection and solrhome parameters, only confname and confdir.

The "confname" parameter is the name of the config in zookeeper (in your case "DMF-index-transformed"), and the "confdir" should be a directory where is your schema.xml (it's better to create a subfolder in your "Desktop" folder, to upload only the schema.xml file instead of all Desktop folder files).

So, the command should look something like this:

```
zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -zkhost 127.0.0.1:9983 -confname DMF-index-transformed -confdir /home/~/Desktop/subfolder
```

Where "subfolder" is the folder with your schema.xml and/or another config files