# How to specify schema.xml and solrconfig.xml in SolrCloud?

Tags: solr, nosql, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

I am learning SolrCloud. I plan to do a schema-full exercise. I don't know much about Solr. So I started with Solr single node(solr start). I created core (items), schema (defined schema.xml and bit changes in solrconfig.xml) and imported data and queried also till here everything fine. After that, I took backup of all Solr-6.5.0 folder. I replaced a fresh copy of Solr-6.5.0.

I run to start

```
cd C:\dev\solr-6.5.0
.\bin\solr -e cloud
```

Given all default ones except collection name as "items".

And after I check the complete solr-6.5.0 folder, but I am not able to identify where should I kept my schema.xml and solrconfig.xml files.

I imported items.csv file successfully. But it is schemaless. How can I configure schema.xml in SolrCloud?

Answer (score 1):

When you're running in cloud / cluster mode, all configuration is kept inside Zookeeper. If you've not set up an external Zookeeper ensemble, Solr will use an embedded version inside each node.

You can either use [the Schema API to add single fields to the managed schema](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html), or use the bundled `zkcli.sh` tool to [upload the configuration to Zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830090/reloading-zookeeper-solr-conf-schema-xml).